# How to reduce the size of a QComboBox with PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox

I created a small program with PyQt in which I put a QComboBox, but this one contains only a list of 2 letters. The program window being small, to save space, I would like to reduce the width of the QComboBox.

This is what it looks like now. The width is too large.

[image: This is what it looks like now. The width is too large.]

I searched the internet, but after a lot of searching time, I still haven't found anything. Thank you in advance if you have an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods to resize a widget's size. Lets say the `QComboBox` is defined as this:

```
combo = QComboBox(self)
```

One way is to use [`QWidget.resize(width, height)`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.resize)

```
combo.resize(200,100)
```

To obtain a proper size automatically, you can use [`QWidget.sizeHint()`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.sizeHint) or [`sizePolicy()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop)

```
combo.resize(combo.sizeHint())
```

If you want to set fixed size, you can use [`setFixedSize(width, height)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize-1), [`setFixedWidth(width)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth), or [`setFixedHeight(height)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight)

```
combo.setFixedSize(400,100)
combo.setFixedWidth(400)
combo.setFixedHeight(100)
```

Here's an example:

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QComboBox, QApplication)
import sys

class ComboboxExample(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel("Ubuntu", self)

        self.combo = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.resize(200,25)
        # self.combo.resize(self.combo.sizeHint())
        # self.combo.setFixedWidth(400)
        # self.combo.setFixedHeight(100)
        # self.combo.setFixedSize(400,100)
        self.combo.addItem("Ubuntu")
        self.combo.addItem("Mandriva")
        self.combo.addItem("Fedora")
        self.combo.addItem("Arch")
        self.combo.addItem("Gentoo")

        self.combo.move(25, 25)
        self.label.move(25, 75)

        self.combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)        

        # self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 125)
        self.setWindowTitle('QComboBox Example')
        self.show()

    def onActivated(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)
        self.label.adjustSize()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ComboboxExample()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```